# How Could I Import Sprite Images To A Java Eclipse Pacman Game?

Tags: java, sprite, css-sprites

I have been writing a Pac-Man game in Java Eclipse. I have gotten the game functioning, movement, sounds, board, etc. However, one problem is that I cannot seem to get the images I used for PacMan and the ghosts to appear, resulting in both being invisible.

I have imported all the images into my project, they are in a folder called "img" in my source file (I'm using Java Eclipse). This is in my build path and everything.

The code I use to import the images to my game is as follows:

```
public class Board extends JPanel
02
{
03
    Image pacmanImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/pacman.jpg");
04
    Image pacmanUpImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/pacmanup.jpg");
05
    Image pacmanDownImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/pacmandown.jpg");
06
    Image pacmanLeftImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/pacmanleft.jpg");
07
    Image pacmanRightImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/pacmanright.jpg");
08
    Image ghost10 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost10.jpg");
09
    Image ghost20 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost20.jpg");
10
    Image ghost30 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost30.jpg");
11
    Image ghost40 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost40.jpg");
12
    Image ghost11 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost11.jpg");
13
    Image ghost21 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost21.jpg");
14
    Image ghost31 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost31.jpg");
15
    Image ghost41 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/ghost41.jpg");
16

17
    Image titleScreenImage =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/titleScreen.jpg");
18
    Image gameOverImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/gameOver.jpg");
19
    Image winScreenImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("PacMan/src/img/winScreen.jpg");
```

Even with the code I have tried putting just `imgname.jpg` to `img/imagename.jpg`, to `src/img/imagename.jpg` to `projectname/src/img/imagename.jpg`, however, nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that the images are in `src/img`, then you should be using the path of `/img/ghost41.jpg`.  But, don;'t use `Toolkit.getImage`, this is look for a file, when the images are embedded within your program they will no longer be available as files, instead use `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(`/img/...`))` instead

Comment: So, the string should look something like this?      Image pacmanImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/pacman.jpg"))  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `swing` you can load the image like this:

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-file"));
```